# "Updating generator object in python, by assigning different values"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, generator

"I have a generator object which generates numbers from 1-n. Now, I want to update the values of the generator object with different values."

## My generator function

```py
def generates(n):
    i = 1
    while n > 0:
        yield i
        i+=1
        n-=1
g = generates(15)
```

## object g has values from 1- n

```py
import math
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2: 
        return False
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
def primes_to_n(n):
    list_ = list()
    i = 1
    while n > 0:
        if is_prime(i):
            list_.append(i)
            n -= 1
        i += 1
    return list_
```

## primes_to_n generates a list of n prime numbers

Now I want to update the original values of the generator function and must return the list of primes as the generator object.

```py
def primes(g, n):
    list_ = primes_to_n(n)
    for i in range(n):
        next(g) = list_[i]
        ## Error while assigning values to next(g)
    return g
```

The desired result = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]

Comment: why not just `def primes(n): return iter(primes_to_n(n))`? (or return the list directly [without the `iter`]).

Comment: "Now, I want to update the values of the generator object with different values." that is a fundamentally flawed way of thinking about things. Generator objects do not *contain values*. They executes and suspends arbitrary code and can *yield values via the iterator protocol that are generated from that code.* Now, a generator can have values injected from the caller, using `.send` on the generator object from the caller taking advantage of the coroutine aspects of generators. but there are likely more straightforward ways to accomplish your program.

Comment: In the generator function, using g.next(), I can print the values from 1 to n. Is there any way to modify those values?